# Angularjs add checkbox 1 or 0 value to mysql with node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, checkbox

I am new to Angular js and I want to try the following.
I have an Object Array that come from Database. This is the url(example): http://localhost:3000/items/showAll
I have yet implemented the Add, Edit, Update, Delete  (Crud operation in backend with nodejs and express js and frontend with angularjs) but my problem is with the checkbox. 
I have in a table in my database a field "state", typ boolean default 0 (1 or 0 value).
I have a list of items(for example 100) and want to select with a checkbox in ng-repeat one or more items and send the value(1) to my filed state in the database. My logic is: I need to bind a single item id with the checkbox, then add a value to the checkbox and if is checked send it to the database.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="state" parse-int ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'" class="form-check-input" >



 [{"id":1,"name":"item1","state":0}]
```

What can I in my controller do?

**Updated:**

Code: Controller

```
$scope.createState = function() {
  var postItem = {
    id : $scope.id,
    state : $scope.state
  };
  itemsService
    .createItem(postItem)
    .then(
      function successCallback(response, data) {

        $scope.clearForm();
      },
      function errorCallback(error, data, status, haders, config) {
        console.log("Error getting: " + data);
      }
    );
};
```

Service:

```
var pathItems = "/items/add";
this.createItem = function(postItem) {
    return $http.post(pathItems, postItem)
};
```

html ng-repeat:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="item.state" ng-click="createState(item.id)">
```

Update the database, api

```
addItem: function(item, id,  callback) {

        return database.query("Update items SET state=? WHERE id=?", [item.state, id], callback);

    },

router.post('/update/', function(req, res, next) {

    items.addItem(req.body, function(error, count) {

        if (error) {

            res.json(error);

        } else {

            res.json(req.body);
        } 


    });
});
```

This can update the database and I can do this from a bootstrap modal. I wanted to do this with a list of one checkbox per user, but I don't now what to do in AngularJS.

Comment: The URL you provided is only accessible from your local machine

Comment: Yes, I now. This is my Array object [{"id":1,"name":"item1","state":0}] . I don't have code

Comment: Do you have an API that changes the state in the database ?

Comment: I have only this INSERT INTO items SET name=?, status=?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from your question every time a checkbox is clicked you want to make an API call with the appropriate state. Attach the state to the `ng-model` of the checkbox. Then on `ng-click` call a function that will make an API call to update the database,

You can have a look at [this code pen](https://codepen.io/DollarAkshay/pen/qpGrEz?editors=1010) for the demo

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
        {{item.name}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="item.state" ng-click="makeAPICall(item.id)"><br>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("controller",
    function($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
            { id: 1, name: "item1", state: 0},
            { id: 2, name: "item2", state: 1},
            { id: 3, name: "item3", state: 0},
            { id: 4, name: "item4", state: 1},
            { id: 5, name: "item5", state: 0}
        ];

        $scope.makeAPICall = function(itemID){
            console.log("Item with id "+itemID+" was changed");
            // Make API call here
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks but this don't send to the database. I updated my question.

Comment: @dani You have to make the API call which will update the database. javascript cannot directly access the database. What does the nodejs API look like ?

Comment: I updated my question with the api. I send the name of the item with the same api and this work, but the state don't work

Comment: I can do it now with a modal bootrap. Edit item, select checkbox, with a update(id). I can't do it in a single page. For example: check 3 checkboxes and send it to the database with a submit button

Comment: do you have an idea to make it with a submit button? Check item1, item2, item3 and send to the database with a submit button outside the ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

The code updated in my question can update the database. For example, if userID=1, check/uncheck the user and update the database. In Angularjs HTML I can do this with a bootstrap modal. Click to a button and check/uncheck the checkbox.